# How to connect from Internet to a a lot of devices behind domestic routers

Tags: rest, websocket, web-applications, architecture, iot

For an IoT related project I need an internet server to be able to interact with devices (they will be small PCs, probably raspberry pi) that will be behind the home router of each user. One of the requirements of the project is that these devices are self-installable by the user.

Therefore the server will not know the public IP of each home router and there is no possibility of NAT configuration in the router to reach each device within the home network.

In this scenario, what possibilities exist? At the moment I am studying the use of websockets initiated from each device to the server on the Internet (in fact, the devices know the server location); over this websocket should run all the communication (in a bidirectional way) simulating a REST interaction between both sides. Is there any other alternative? What do you think about the use of websockets to solve this need?

Comment: Did you eared about UPnP protocol ? You can also look how the notification system (Apple, Android, etc) work you find some answers.

Comment: By envisioning the IoT devices as clients that independently connect to a known server you essentially solve the issue of having the server attempt to connect to nodes that are behind a router / firewall... however, you will still need the user to connect the IoT devices to the local wifi / network.

Comment: Yes, but that process can be simplified either by having the device connected directly by cable to the router or by a process of pairing to the home wireless network

Answer (score 1):

[Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) are used for interactive communication between a client and a server. By 'interactive' I understand near real-time. If this is your requirement, then you can use it.

If you only need non-interactive communication (request / response), you can use a classical REST API over HTTP, initiated from the devices. As long as they are connected to the router, the network stack takes care of everything.

You need to know the public IP of a router *only* when the server has to initiate the connection to a specific PC/workstation. In that case, a NAT rule has to be set up on the router which directs the traffic to the right workstation in the local network.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I said in my initial message, I need an internet server to be able to interact with the devices. Therefore I need a way to access from the internet (with a known IP or domain) to every device behind the home network using an heterogeneous infraestructure. And the idea is that there would be a very lot of devices that are not under my control. That´s the challenge

Comment: Okay, I see. I believe the crucial detail in the initial message was "who initiates the connection", and definitely if the devices are doing that, the problem is easy. Otherwise, if the server have to initiate it, then I don't see many options here.